How to monitor internet traffic from/to an Android device using a (desktop) Linux
I want to monitor internet traffic from/to an Android device that's connected to the same router as my linux computer. The Android device communicates with a web server. I tried using tcdump and wireshark but they don't capture anything.
Router model: Linksys MX4200 v2.
Linux commands used: sudo tcpdump -i wlp3s0 host 192.168.1.x -w vr_logs.pcap.
The Android device is connected to the wireless interface wlp3so and is pinging.
Why is the network traffic not being captured by the Linux? I specifically want bandwidth, packet loss, packets transmitted, latency, jitter.
